# Run Chromium on windows instance on EC2 on startup

Tags: powershell, user-interface, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chromium

I have an application which uses Chromium (v39) installed on EC2 (amazon cloud) windows instance.

When I logon to a user via remote desktop (RDP) and double click on the application everything works fine.

But when I tried to inject powershell command to the startup (in AWS console by right click on instance then "Instance Settings" -> "View/Change User Data") I see chromium on background tasks but it seems it was not loaded properly and in chromium logs I see "Failed to launch child process"

Any idea o how to run GUI application on start as normal logged on user?

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a task in order to achieve that. Details [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html).

I was looking into the same issue today, and it seems to happen only when running Chrome as an admin. Thus, try to schedule your task to run as Standard user. If you still want to run as admin, see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305809/failed-to-launch-child-process) thread, there is another workaround.