# Failed to launch child process

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, child-process, rake-task

When I try to run a test on Chrome (selenium / Ruby) then I get the following error. Could anybody help to resolve this?

Error :-

> Background: Login to app # tests\integration\channels.feature:3
>   [6100:7920:1028/134946:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(533)] Failed to
>   launch child process
>   [6100:9520:1028/134946:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(533)] Failed to
>   launch child process
>   [6100:9520:1028/134946:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(533)] Failed to
>   launch child process
>   [6100:9520:1028/134949:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(533)] Failed to
>   launch child process
>   [6100:9520:1028/134955:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(533)] Failed to
>   launch child process
>   [6100:9520:1028/135006:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(533)] Failed to
>   launch child process rake aborted!

Following are the gems installed:- 
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.13.6, 1.11.2)
childprocess (0.5.0)
cucumber (2.4.0, 1.3.2)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
debase (0.2.1, 0.1.4)
debase-ruby_core_source (0.9.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
ffi (1.9.14 x86-mingw32)
gherkin (4.0.0, 2.12.2 x86-mingw32)
io-console (default: 0.4.2)
json (2.0.2, default: 1.7.7)
minitest (default: 4.3.2)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
parallel (1.6.1)
parallel_tests (1.3.7)
psych (default: 2.0.0)
rake (10.1.0, default: 0.9.6)
rdoc (default: 4.0.0)
ruby-debug-ide (0.6.0, 0.4.32)
rubyzip (1.2.0, 1.1.7)
selenium-webdriver (2.52.0, 2.48.0, 2.46.2)
test-unit (default: 2.0.0.0)
websocket (1.2.3, 1.2.2)
```

I am using:-

```
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'cucumber', '1.3.2'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.0'
gem 'rake', '10.1.0'
gem 'appium_lib', '8.0.2'
gem 'json', '1.8.3'

gem 'parallel_tests', '1.3.7'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Chrome 54.0.2840.71. The issue only reproduces for me when running chrome as administrator (on windows). A couple of workarounds you can use:

1. If you were running as admin, try running unelevated and it might fix your issue.
2. Disable the Chrome Zygote process when launching. Beware, this will disable the chrome sandbox and you might have security risks.

   `chrome.exe --no-zygote --no-sandbox`